# Reshape dataframe based on a column and separate it by a comma in result rows in R

Tags: r, reshape

I want to reshape data like the following

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4),A=c("a","c","a","b"),B=c("b","a","c","c"))
```

*data*

[image]

And I want to reshape the data by sorting the data in columns A and B (a,b,c) based on the id column and return the ids related to that data separated by a comma. The result I want is as follows:

*reshape_data*

[image]

I'm really sorry but I have no idea to do this. Can someone help or suggest me? I'm so grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape the data to long format, then back to wide on the values of the original data set, `paste` the `id` numbers and done.

```r
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4),A=c("a","c","a","b"),B=c("b","a","c","c"))

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = value,
    names_from = name,
    values_from = id,
    values_fn = list
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(A = paste(A, collapse = ","),
         B = paste(B, collapse = ","))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   value A     B    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     1,3   2    
#> 2 b     4     1    
#> 3 c     2     3,4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>